# Obtaining MS Ribbon UI - Office UI Licensing Site - Page Cannot Be Found?

Tags: wpf, ribbon

Can anyone actually download the RibbonControlsLibrary from the MS Office UI Fluent Site? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809.aspx)

I fill in the form, sign it, enter a name of my application (test) and it then redirects to a page saying "Page Cannot Be Found" from the following URL http://microsoftio.partnersalesresources.com/officeUI/license/ .

I can't seem to get the Ribbon UI from MS!

Anyone know what might be going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a download link I found, check it out:

http://daisy-trac.cvsdude.com/tobi/export/129/trunk/tobiapp/ExternalLibs/RibbonControlsLibrary.dll

Download at your own risk

**[Update]**

According to Tometzky who checked the Digital Signature, the file is safe to download and use.

Comment: I'd not recommend downloading anything executable from a random link.

Comment: It's not an executable...it's a dll; just add reference to it and see if it works; what more can I say; the guy needed a link and I found him one

Comment: I checked it out with Reflector, its Kosha. Thanks Dreas!

Comment: ...it's what?  what's a kosha?

Comment: Any dll is executable, when used in a program. You can not know what any exported function does. It can be named "init_library" and do something nasty, like install spyware or a rootkit on your computer. This is the Internet - trust no one.

Comment: Hmm I guess you're right about that Tometzky.  I'll add a warning to the post.

Comment: I think he meant "Kosher," as in, "it's okay."

Comment: oh, well it must mean that it's alright.  I checked it now with Reflector, and it seems quite ok, but as Tometzky said, I guess you can never be too careful

Comment: OK. The DLL is signed by Microsoft, so it should be safe. But check this signature before use - right-click on a file to get Properties, tab Signatures then Details. If it says it is OK, then it is.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "site feedback" link in [Office UI Licensing page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809.aspx). I'd recommend using it.

Comment: Done That! - Had no response so far

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they are aware and working on it.

Quoted from http://wpf.codeplex.com/wiki/comments/view?title=Home

> I spoke to the Office Licensing team
>   about this and this is what they had
>   to say: "Yes, unfortunately our web
>   site hosting group has reorganized
>   some of the sites and pages on the
>   backend and unfortunately our ribbon
>   UI licensing pages got disconnected.
>   They are working to remedy the
>   situation and we hope to have the
>   pages back up very soon." I will post
>   back here as soon as I hear that the
>   page is back up. I apologize for the
>   delay.
>
> *yesterday by SamanthaMSFT*

Answer (score 0):

I've got it from http://docs.fairwaydev.com/misc/wpftoolkit/
. It appears to be the official one as well, since the site is down.